# Replacing a value in a table and then joining it to another table

Tags: sql, join, case, tableau-api

brand new to the site and this is my first question! Sorry I am very limited in SQL skills. I mostly use Tableau but need to create a custom SQL join in Tableau.

I have 2 tables (C table and P table) that will need to be joined by the "Orders"  field (found in both tables) and "Prefix" field (only found in C table but looking to change values in the "contract" field in P table to do the join). It is just two values that need to be changed. If contract="1234", it will be changed to "ABC. And it contract="5678" it will be changed to "XYZ".

Once those values are changed, Contract from P table can be joined to Prefix from C Table.

Sorry I couldnt explain this better but like I said I have very limited experience in SQL. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a subquery.

```
select * 
    from C
    inner join (
        select *,
                case contract when 1234 then ABC
                              when 5678 then XYZ
                              else contract
                end as changed_contract -- or whatever name you like
            from P
    ) P on P.changed_contract = C.prefix
        and P.orders = C.orders
```

The table in the subquery will give you all the fields from P including a new field that takes into a account the modifications you made. Then you just join on that new field and change your select statement to grab the fields you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` to modify `contract` for certain values. Like:

```
select  prefix + ' ' + case contract
        when '1234' then 'ABC'
        when '5678' then 'XYZ'
        else contract
        end as prefix_plus_contract
,       *
from    c
join    p
on      c.orders = p.orders
```